# Thread safe access to a variable in a class

Tags: multithreading, swift

in an application where there could be multiple threads running, and not sure about the possibilities if these methods will be accessed under a multhreaded environment or not but to be safe, I've done a test class to demonstrate a situation.

One method `has` was programmed to be thread safe (please also comment if it's done right) but the rest were not.

In a situation like this, where there is only one single line of code inside `remove` and `add`, is it necessary to make them thread safe or is it going to be exaggeration.

```
import Foundation

class Some {}

class Test {
    var dict = [String: Some]()

    func has(key: String) -> Bool {
        var has = false
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_queue_create("has", nil), { [unowned self] in
            has = self.dict[key] != nil
        })
        return has
    }

    func remove(key: String) -> Some {
        var ob = dict[key]
        dict[key] = nil
        return ob
    }

    func add(key: String, ob: Some) {
        dict[key] = ob
    }
}
```

**Edit after comments**

```
class Some {}

class Test {
    var dict = [String: Some]()
    private let queue: dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_queue_create("has", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)

    func has(key: String) -> Bool {
        var has = false
        dispatch_sync(queue) {
            has = self.dict[key] != nil
        }
        return has
    }

    func remove(key: String) -> Some? { //returns
        var removed: Some?
        dispatch_barrier_sync(queue) {
            removed = self.dict.removeValueForKey(key)
        }
        return removed
    }

    func add(key: String, ob: Some) { //not async
        dispatch_barrier_sync(queue) {
            self.dict[key] = ob
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you are checking whether a key exists is incorrect. You are creating a new queue every time, which means the operations are not happening synchronously.

The way I would do it is like so:

```
class Some {}

class Test {
    var dict = [String: Some]()
    private let queue: dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_queue_create("has", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)

    func has(key: String) -> Bool {
        var has = false
        dispatch_sync(queue) { [weak self] in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

            has = strongSelf.dict[key] != nil
        }

        return has
    }

    func remove(key: String) {
        dispatch_barrier_async(queue) { [weak self] in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

            strongSelf.dict[key] = nil
        }
    }

    func add(key: String, ob: Some) {
        dispatch_barrier_async(queue) { [weak self] in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

            strongSelf.dict[key] = ob
        }
    }
}
```

Firstly, I am creating a serial queue that is going to be used to access the dictionary as a property of the object, rather than creating a new one every time. The queue is private as it is only used internally.

When I want to get a value out of the class, I am just dispatching a block synchronously to the queue and waits for the block to finish before returning whether or not the queue exists. Since this is not mutating the dictionary, it is safe for multiple blocks of this sort to run on the concurrent queue.

When I want to add or remove values from the dictionary, I am adding the block to the queue but with a barrier. What this does is that it stops all other blocks on the queue while it is running. When it is finished, all the other blocks can run concurrently. I am using an async dispatch, because I don't need to wait for a return value.

Imagine you have multiple threads trying to see whether or not key values exist or adding or removing values. If you have lots of reads, then they happen concurrently, but when one of the blocks is run that will change the dictionary, all other blocks wait until this change is completed and then start running again.

In this way, you have the speed and convenience of running concurrently when getting values, and the thread safety of blocking while the dictionary is being mutated.

**Edited to add**

`self` is marked as `weak` in the block so that it doesn't create a reference cycle. As @MartinR mentioned in the comments; it is possible that the object is deallocated while blocks are still in the queue, If this happens then self is undefined, and you'll probably get a runtime error trying to access the dictionary, as it may also be deallocated.

By setting declaring `self` within the block to be weak, if the object exists, then `self` will not be nil, and can be conditionally unwrapped into `strongSelf` which points to `self` and also creates a strong reference, so that `self` will not be deallocated while the instructions in the block are carried out. When these instructions complete, `strongSelf` will go out of scope and release the strong reference to self.

This is sometimes known as the "strong self, weak self dance".

**Edited Again : Swift 3 version**

```
class Some {}

class Test {
    var dict = [String: Some]()
    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "has", qos: .default, attributes: .concurrent)

    func has(key: String) -> Bool {
        var has = false
        queue.sync { [weak self] in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

            has = strongSelf.dict[key] != nil
        }

        return has
    }

    func remove(key: String) {
        queue.async(flags: .barrier) { [weak self] in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

            strongSelf.dict[key] = nil
        }
    }

    func add(key: String, ob: Some) {
        queue.async(flags: .barrier) { [weak self] in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

            strongSelf.dict[key] = ob
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! One question though: Wouldn't `[weak self]` be safer? The `Test` object might be deallocated when the barrier block executes.

Comment: @MartinR In which case, wouldn't the queue that the block is running on be deallocated as well?

Comment: From [dispatch_barrier_async()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_barrier_async): *"The queue is retained by the system until the block has run to completion."* – So (I think that) even if the object is deallocated and releases its reference to the queue, the queue will continue to run until all outstanding block are completed.

Comment: @Abizern If I also have another dictionary, lets say `dict2`, should I declare another `dispatch_queue_t` variable for `dict2`s `has`, `remove` and `add` functions

Comment: @user2727195 If you have another dictionary, then using a different queue is a good idea. There is no point blocking getters for one dictionary because you are mutating a different one.

Comment: @Abizern Can you please explain some more on about the `[weak self]` in the answer, I'm newbie when it comes to threading

Comment: @Abizern: It might be possible to avoid the "strongSelf" with optional chaining: `has = self?.dict[key] != nil`. But I am not 100% if that is thread-safe. – One could also consider to just use `self` (without unowned/weak). All blocks are executed eventually, so any retain cycle is only temporary.

Comment: @MartinR Both good points, but I'll leave it in as it shows the strong weak dance in action.

Comment: Great explanation, loved the concurrency + thread safety combination

Comment: have been running into problems while unit testing for the remove since it was returning a value (not in my question), after reading some more on `dispatch_barrier_async`, changed it `sync` call. Any apple doc link that you recommend to read in depth about it.

Comment: Asked another question to apply the same functionality within static functions, (there are other approaches on SO with static lazy instantiation with build-in thread safety but for some reason I've to go this way) please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839595/gcd-with-static-functions-of-a-struct

Comment: quick question, I didn't get on the use of `[weak self] in` inside `dispatch_sync`, IMHO the block is executed immediately while the object is live, so why creating a weak reference. on the other hand for `dispatch_barrier_async` it makes sense, as it's an async call and by the time the block starts executing the object maybe dead, please advise and correct me.

Comment: As Martin said it probably isn't necessary in this case.

Comment: @user2727195 I don't think it's necessary in the case of `dispatch_barrier_async` either. There is only a retain cycle whilst the block is waiting to be executed on the queue. 

Unless you're using `dispatch_suspend` and `dispatch_resume`, and there is a risk that the queue will be permanently suspended, it doesn't look like the weak/strong self dance is needed here.

Comment: @alexbird I've edited my question with sample code, just to make it clear to myself, please review and comment if my approach is valid. I've removed weak self based on the comments.

Comment: @user2727195 Yes, I think that's right. It's analogous to (not) `@escaping` in Swift. The dispatch barrier waits, synchronously, until it can run its closure. It never runs it after the function returns, so capturing `self` should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another swift 3 solution which provides thread-safe access to AnyObject.

It allocates recursive pthread_mutex associated with 'object' if needed.

```
class LatencyManager
{
    private var latencies = [String : TimeInterval]()

    func set(hostName: String, latency: TimeInterval) {
        synchronizedBlock(lockedObject: latencies as AnyObject) { [weak self] in
            self?.latencies[hostName] = latency
        }
    }

    /// Provides thread-safe access to given object
    private func synchronizedBlock(lockedObject: AnyObject, block: () -> Void) {
        objc_sync_enter(lockedObject)
        block()
        objc_sync_exit(lockedObject)
    }
}
```

Then you can call for example `set(hostName: "stackoverflow.com", latency: 1)`

**UPDATE**

You can simply define a method in a swift file (not in a class):

```
/// Provides thread-safe access to given object
public func synchronizedAccess(to object: AnyObject, _ block: () -> Void)
{
    objc_sync_enter(object)
    block()
    objc_sync_exit(object)
}
```

And use it like this:

```
synchronizedAccess(to: myObject) {
    myObject.foo()
 }
```