# Swift 3: atomic_compare_exchange_strong

Tags: swift, atomic

Getting following warning in Xcode 8 / Swift 3:

```
warning: 'OSAtomicCompareAndSwap32Barrier' was deprecated in OS X 10.12:
         Use atomic_compare_exchange_strong() from <stdatomic.h> instead
```

Attempt to use function `atomic_compare_exchange_strong` in Swift code leads compiler error:

```
error: use of unresolved identifier 'atomic_compare_exchange_strong'
```

Importing `Darwin` or `CoreFoundation` modules does not solve problem.

What module should I import in order to get symbol for `atomic_compare_exchange_strong`?

Thank you!

Comment: I would have said `import Darwin.C.stdatomic` - or even `#include <stdatomic.h>` in a bridging header, but it doesn't bring `atomic_compare_exchange_strong` when I test it. And I see  https://openradar.appspot.com/27161329 so maybe it's just not there yet.

Comment: So does this mean APPLE is forcing us into the standard lib now? Not good.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a question for Swift 3, but in case anyone stumbles across this, now there is a [Swift Atomics package](https://github.com/apple/swift-atomics) ([introduced in Oct 2020](https://swift.org/blog/swift-atomics/)) which can be used for this functionality.