# How to create UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer> in swift

Tags: swift

The function:

```
public func OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtr(_ __oldValue: UnsafeMutableRawPointer!, _ __newValue: UnsafeMutableRawPointer!, ___theValue: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutableRawPointer?>!) -> Bool
```

requires a type of `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutableRawPointer?>` for the a parameter `theValue` but I'm having trouble figuring out how to make one from a type `UnsafeMutablePointer<T?>`

Any thoughts on how I could do this?

EDIT:

for the curious about why I am trying to do this, I am trying to create a generic wrapper around this to create a bounded MPMC queue in swift as outlined in this [blog post](http://www.1024cores.net/home/lock-free-algorithms/queues/bounded-mpmc-queue). Here is my wrapper so far

```
func compareAndSwap<T: AnyObject>(current: T?, future: T?, toPtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<T?>) -> Bool {
    let currentPtr = current.map(Unmanaged.passUnretained)?.toOpaque()
    let futurePtr = future.map(Unmanaged.passRetained)?.toOpaque()

    if OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtr(currentPtr, futurePtr, ????) {
        return true
    }
    return false
```

Comment: Why do you need to call this function? Please show us the code that uses this.

Comment: @kennytm I've added an explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 3, [use `.withMemoryRebound`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unsafemutablepointer/2428492-withmemoryrebound) to reinterpret-cast that "`T**`" pointer to a "`void**`" pointer:

```
return toPtr.withMemoryRebound(to: (UnsafeMutableRawPointer?).self, capacity: 1) {
    OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtr(currentPtr, futurePtr, $0)
}
```

Note that

- OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtr has been deprecated in favor of the C11 functions like `atomic_compare_and_exchange_strong`, which [unfortunately you cannot use in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39356873/swift-3-atomic-compare-exchange-strong). This is [a known issue](https://openradar.appspot.com/27161329).
- The blog post's atomic operations uses "acquire", "release" and also "relaxed" memory order. The OSAtomic libraries provides only the "seq_cst" and "relaxed" order (the Barrier vs non-Barrier variant of each function). So your Swift translation cannot be a 1:1 functional copy of the C++ code.

---

There is also a [thin wrapper library `timehop/Atomics`](https://github.com/timehop/Atomics) which hides all the dangerous casts for you (it is not generic, however).

```
var toPtr = HOPAtomicReference(object: ...)
...
return toPtr.compareTo(current, andSetObject: future)
```

Comment: thanks for the help, is there a place you found the info on OSAtomic or is that just from looking at the source?

Comment: You could check the manpage. [`man 3 atomic_deprecated`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/atomic_deprecated/). The [header file](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-763.12/include/libkern/OSAtomic.h.auto.html) is more detailed though.